# Optimizing Innodb table indexes with GUID/UUID keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, clustered-index

I have an InnoDB based schema with roughly 100 tables, most use GUID/UUID's as the primary key.  I started this at a point in time where I didn't really understand the implications of a UUID PK with regard to Disk IO and fragmentation, but wanted the benefits of avoiding a single key dispenser when dealing with server clusters. We're not currently dealing with large numbers of rows, but we will be (in the hundreds of millions) and I would like to be prepared for that.

Now that I understand indexing in InnoDB better, specifically the clustered nature of the primary key, I can see that my UUID's are a poor choice for scalability from a DISK IO perspective, but I don't want to stop using them due to the server clustering requirement.

The accepted/recommended solution seems to be a mix of Autoincrement PK (INT|BIGINT), with UNIQUE Indexed UUID keys. My intention is to add a new first column `ai_col` to each table and assign it as the new PK, I'm taking queues from:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

I would then update/recreate a new "UNIQUE" index on my UUID keys and continue to use them in our application layer.

My expectation is that once this is done that I can essentially ignore the `ai_col` and everything else runs business as usual.  InnoDB will have a relatively small int based PK from which to cluster on and append to the other unique indexes.

**Question 1:** Am I correct in assuming that in this new scenario, I can have my cake and eat it too?

The follow up question is with regard to smaller 'associational' tables, i.e. Only two columns, both Foreign Keys to other tables joining them implicitly.  In these cases I have typically two indexes, one being a UNIQUE two column index with the more heavily used column first, then a second single index on the other column.  I know that this is essentially 2.5x as large as the actual row data, but it seems to really help our more complex queries during optimization, and is on smaller tables so relatively acceptable.

Most of these associational tables will only be a fraction the number of records in the primary tables because they're typically more specific, however, there are a few cases where these have many multiples the number of records as their foreign parents, i.e. potentially billions.

**Question 2:** Is it a good idea to add the numeric PK's to these tables as well?  I'm guessing that the answer will be something along the lines of "Benchtest it" but I'm just looking for helpful nuggets of wisdom.

If I've obviously mis-interpreted anything or you can offer insights that I may not be considering, I'd really appreciate that too!

Many thanks!

---

**EDIT:** As promised in the answer, I just wanted to follow up for anyone interested... This solution has worked famously :)  Read and write performance increased across the board, and so far it's been tested up to about 6 billion i/o's / month, without breaking a sweat.

Comment: It's been a little while longer and I'm curious as to how this has worked out.  Have you had to make any changes are you able to handle the load still?

Comment: @John Hey! The space requirements have been negligible compared to the data we're storing so that hasn't been an issue at all.  In the end with proper indexing, this is as good as any solution using only AI columns, but with all the benefits of UUID's.  The one additional thing we've started doing though to compact even further is to store the UUID's in BINARY(16) rather than CHAR(32) and use `HEX()` and `UNHEX()` to convert.  Minimal overhead and half the space.

Comment: @John Just one further thought, I've seen other solutions proposed that adjust the structure of UUID's so that the first segment of the UUID is time based and thus avoids the problem of rebuilding/resorting tables after inserts and the corresponding high IO in large tables, however that eliminates the ability to store in BINARY so you don't get the space optimization I mentioned above, and requires a little extra work to write UUID validation scripts since it's no longer compatible with built in mechanisms.  They probably still work fine, but I think this method is more logical and standard.

Comment: thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other suggestions, confirmations, or otherwise, I've begun testing on our dev server with a number of less used tables but ones that would be affected none the less if the new AI based id's were going to affect our application layer.

So far it's looking good, indexes are performing as expected and the new table fields haven't required any changes to our application layer, we've been basically able to ignore them.

I haven't run any thorough bench testing though to test the actual Disk IO under heavy load but from the sheer amount of information out there on the subject, I can surmise that we're in good shape for scaling up.

Once this has been in place for a while I'll drop in a follow up in case anyone's in the same boat we were.